# SQL Server - Output single XML file per single row in the table or select statement

Tags: sql-server, xml, string, reporting, for-xml-path

I have a XML file that uses columns of the table as a elements. The question that I'm trying to resolve:

1) how to produce a single XML file per each record in the select statement;

2) save each xml file with a unique name based on rowId on a shared server

The problem here is that FOR XML and XML data type are not allowed in the Cursor statement.

```
CREATE TABLE #T1 
(
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    LName NVARCHAR(30) NULL,
    FName NVARCHAR(30) NULL,
    Comments NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL
);

GO

INSERT INTO #T1 (ID, LName, FName, Comments)
    VALUES
        (1, 'JONOTHAN', 'SMITH', 'is the best friend ever'),
        (2, 'ROGER', 'SHU`LTS', 'is the boss!'),
        (3, 'Jeremy', 'Deimer', 'is the a good drama actor'),
        (4, 'Alexandra', 'Norusis', 'is the smart feminist');

GO

SELECT 
    t.ID, 
    t.LName, 
    t.FName, 
    t.Comments
FROM #T1 t
    FOR XML PATH('BODY') --, ROOT ('MyProject');
```

The root tag above is commented out as I my desired XML file output "Body" specified in the "FOR XML PATH('BODY')" will be the root tag itself as I should have one XML file per each row of data.

Below is the desired output of the XML file format:

```
<Body>
  <Project>2538</Project>
  <Title>SERVICE, MAINTENANCE, REPAIR, TESTING </Title>
  <Summary> Install cabling and provide testing of cabling for </Summary>
  <Requirement>Operations Maintenance|</Requirement>
  <CodeDescription>93609 - Alarm Equipment|</CodeDescription>
</Body>
```

Comment: Writing multiple files will need a `CURSOR`, dynamically created `BCP` commands and `EXEC`. There are many examples around. Btw: Your eample is not very clear... How is the table and the XML connected?

Comment: My table is just a sample. And thanks for your tips Shnugo. I'll try to find examples of this.

Comment: Hi Shnugo, just wanted to point that The FOR XML clause is not allowed in CURSOR statement.

Comment: No need for this ... The Cursor is for the literal parts of bcp (filename, Statement Creation ...)